# Mystery Package when adding a new SCCM Distribution Point

Tags: sccm, system-center

My SCCM hierarchy has three Distribution Points and I am adding a fourth.

The new Distribution Point is added successfully, and when I check Content Status I see that all of my content items are now properly targeting all four Distribution Points, with the exception of one package:

- Microsoft Corporation Configuration Manager Client Piloting Upgrade Package

This package still only targets the original three.

When browsing through the Packages list (via Software Library | Packages) this Package is **not** visible.

Using PowerShell, `Get-CMPackage` with the ID of this package returns nothing.  Likewise `Get-CMPackage | ft PackageId` doesn't list the package ID (it does list my other packages correctly).

How do I amend this package to target the new fourth Distribution Point?

Comment: Is there any info referring to it in distmgr.log or despool.log?

Comment: @Crimsonfox - no, not in either.  Confirming also that I've searched for the package by ID, not by name, and that my other packages are present, likewise by ID, not name.

Comment: Does it show in the Content Library Explorer?

Comment: @Crimsonfox - yes on the 3 previously-existing distribution points, no on the new one.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.vansurksum.com/2012/11/25/configmgr-2012-what-to-do-when-the-configuration-manager-client-upgrade-package-is-deleted-somehow/#comment-4511  but renaming ccmsetup in the the PilotingUpgrade folder too?

Comment: Actually, instead of adding the client.acu file, try CliUpg.acu, that should recreate the packages as opposed to just redistributing them.

Also, check if there is any reference in DataTransferService.log or PkgXferMgr.log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the absence of a documented solution from Microsoft outlining the procedure for redistributing this package, and explaining what it is and why it appears the way it does, I have decommissioned the new Distribution Point and will engage Microsoft Support for the next steps.